Keyboard is not working on my Dell machine
I bought a new pc Dell inspiron 14 7000 gaming series with Nvidia GTX 1050 ti the old one I had didn't have any graphics card and I used Ubuntu with no problem but on the new one I dual booted windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04 but my keyboard is not working on Ubuntu it worked fine on windows just doesn't work on Ubuntu. I have searched everywhere but I can't find a solution. Someone said it might be the Nvidia driver I installed but I purged it and it's still the same as always it works for the first two keys and then it stops I have to restart it again to make it work.
